# string.Contains could not be translated

Tags: c#

This is my first post in this site.

I have a list of vehicles in my database and every vehicle has a Vin (License Plate Number, in example "6TRJ244", it is a string value).

I receive a list of search values, in example "A", "B","J"

I need to filter the vehicles which Vin Contains one of the search values.
In example if I have three vehicles with Vin: Vehicle1_Vin = "123AJ", Vehicle2_Vin = "123BJ", Vehicle3_Vin = "777CR"

If I receive as search values "X", "A","C" I should return Vehicles 1 and 3

With LINQ I am trying to do something like this

```
var searchParams = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C"};

vehicles = vehicles.Where((vehicle) => searchParams.Any((searchParam) => vehicle.Vin.Contains(searchParam)));
```

But I receive this error message

"System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'searchParam => EntityShaperExpression:
ProjectAlpha.BusinessObjects.Models.Vehicle
ValueBufferExpression:
ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
IsNullable: False
.Vin.Contains(searchParam)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

Thanks ins advance!

Comment: You need to use the [`SqlMethods`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods?view=netframework-4.8.1) class for operations like this that cannot be converted to SQL. In this case, the `Like` method is what you want.

Comment: Having said that, LINQ to SQL is basically obsolete these days. I recommend that you switch to using Entity Framework if possible. It works similarly to LINQ to SQL, provides more functionality for SQL Server and supports many more data sources besides.

Comment: I removed the linq-to-sql tag. It's not LINQ-to-SQL. Please add the tag belonging to the EF version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You could try use functions if you are using net core try with something like this

```
IQueryable<T> nightClub = nightClub.Where(nc => EF.Functions.Like(nc.Name, "%Dfox%");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what collection type vehicles variable is so better introduce new variable or transfer IEnumerable to same type as source collection (ToArray/ToList etc):

```
var searchParams = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C"};
var filtered = vehicles.Where(vehicle => searchParams.Any(vehicle.Vin.Contains));
```